# How do I JSON parse a Django queryset?

Tags: python, json, django

So I'm trying to parse each object in my Django queryset, and deal with the data through JavaScript. Below is my code (simplified) :
views.py (using Django Paginator, but the basic idea is the same.)

```
def main_page(request):
    all_contents = Contents.objects.all()
    paginator_contents = Paginator(contents,10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    all_contents_paginated = paginator_contents.get_page(page)

    context = {
            'contents' : contents,
            'all_contents_paginated' : all_contents_paginated
        }

    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

template

```
{% for c in all_contents_paginated %}
<div class="text-m">
    {{c.author}}
</div>
<div class="text-s" onclick="DetailModal('{{c}}')">
    {{c.body}}
</div>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function DetailModal(c) {

    }
</script>
```

Now obviously, the `'{{c}}'` cannot be parsed into JSON since it's string. I want to parse it into JSON in `function DetailModal()` and display the data in a separate modal element or do any other stuff with each data. But I can't figure out how to parse each object in the Django queryset.

 Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just modify your script to parse your item:

```
<script>
    function DetailModal(c) {
       const obj = JSON.parse(c);
       console.log(obj.author);   
       console.log(obj.body);
    }
</script>
```